# Making Silverlight 2 programs work in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight

I am trying to make Jeff's testing program, written in Silverlight 2 (http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/03/silverlight2-unit-testing/), work using Silverlight 4 and VS2010 and I get a NullReferenceException at this line:
    chatSession.ConnectWithRemoteUser("ScottGu");
Any ideas why? Here's code:

```
public Page()
{
    // commented out because it doesn't exist in the current context 
    // according to the compiler
    // InitializeComponent();

    // Retrieve ChatSession instance from XAML resource declaration
    chatSession = new ChatSession();
    chatSession = (ChatSession)Resources["ChatSessionDS"];

    // Connect with Chat Server to chat with "ScottGu"
    chatSession.ConnectWithRemoteUser("ScottGu");
}
```

Comment: Please tell us which line fails.

Comment: chatSession.ConnectWithRemoteUser("ScottGu");

Comment: Obviously, chatSession is null... so it is not in the Resources dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you had to comment out `InitializeComponent()`, I Feel bad about your application: InitializeComponent is generated by the VS tools when the XAML file of your page is parsed.

If it doesn't exist, it probably means that the class declared in the xaml file is different from the one in your c# file (different name or different namespace) Otherwise, maybe the XAML file action type in the VS property tab isn't set to "page".

second:

```
chatSession = new ChatSession();
chatSession = (ChatSession)Resources["ChatSessionDS"];
```

this looks strange.you create a new ChatSession, then replace it by an object saved in the page resources. Why do you create it firstplace if you put the instance out of scope at the next line?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll play around with your code change advice. I think it fails because of data source binding works differently for SL2 and SL4.